# How to map nested values of dictionary into array in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Type of `selectBoxItems` is `[String : [String : SelectBoxTextField]]`

I want to map `selectBoxItems` to get the result as `[SelectBoxTextField]`

How can I do it?

Comment: `selectBoxItems.values.flatMap { $0.values }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
selectBoxItems.values.flatMap(\.values)
```